# Using std::forward for other than forwarding args to another function

Tags: c++, std, forward

I have a number of methods of the following form

```
foo(std::string const & name)
    if (name.empty()) {...}
```

I was trying to follow Scott Meyers' note on using universal references and std::forward to make a function that efficiently takes a number of string forms.

From example, I understand how to use std::forward to forward a function argument to another function, but what do I do about the name.empty() expression?

I think the answer is std::forward(name).empty() but I can find any documentation that actually says that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::forward` only when you actually need to forward the value category. That is, `std::forward` is used to guarantee that if your function is called with an lvalue argument then it will call another function with an lvalue argument, and if your function is called with an rvalue argument then it will call another function with an rvalue argument.

In the case where you want to check whether a string is empty, it doesn't matter whether the argument was an lvalue or rvalue---the `string::empty` function should not behave differently. So you don't need `std::forward`. Instead, just `name.empty()` suffices.

Comment: And using `std::forward` more than once on the same parameter is most probably a mistake anyway, since rvalues are likely to be moved away at the first occurrence of `std::forward`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to figure out when to use `std::forward`.

Imagine your incoming argument was, instead of a `T&& t` just a `T t` -- a value parameter instead of a forwarding reference.  If you would call `std::move(t)` in the second case, calling `std::forward<T>(t)` in the first case is a good idea.

`std::forward` is a conditional move.  It will invoke the `move` iff the reference was an rvalue passed in, and will do mostly nothing if it wasn't an rvalue.

The next question is, when should you `move` a value parameter?

Well, the first general rule is you should move a value parameter the last time you'll ever refer to it in its scope.  You are marking its state as "scratch" and that it be recycled in that last operation.

There are a few other places to use `move`.

If you are breaking it down into individual components (like the parts of a tuple), and you know the access will be isolated to the part (`std::get<N>`, or `.member`), and there are no invariants that will be violated, then `move` will tell the code that the component can be torn out of the object.  You can end up calling `move` on the same variable multiple times in this sense, but each time you are conceptually only moving one part of it.

This is sometimes distinct from calling `move` on the component itself, as `std::get<i>(std::move(foo))` will behave differently than `std::move( std::get<i>(foo) )` when `foo` contains reference parameters.